# How to query for abbreviation of data in a column?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query an abbreviation of data I have in a column. For example, say I have all cities in the USA within a column. I want to query 'NY' and get back the row that has 'New York'. Is there any way to do this in Postgres?

Comment: No, because the database engine has no way to know that `NY` is `New York`. Why don't you just have a state abbreviation column in your table if you need to be able to query it that way? And if you don't have such a column, why can't you just query using `New York` instead?

Comment: It is possible to approximate this but it's not going to work for all cities, the correct abbreviation to match against would normally be stored as a column in the data table. If you post some example data, we can assist in how to create or fake such a column but also demonstrate where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could achieve this.

1. You could create a mapping table which holds they initials and state names in two columns.  Then you could use join statement to join the two tables and use where condition on the mapping table initials column.
2. Second method is to use a select statement with a derived column from the states column. This derived table will have the initials of the states.  You could first use split by space,  use left(string) method to get the first alphabet and join them together.  Now you could have a where condition on this new derived initials column.  But the drawback here is that you will get only one initial if the state is one word only.